# Data Validation from one table with another

Tags: sql, mysql, hive

I'm trying to think of the most efficient way to check if data from one table has changed in another. Ex:

Table a

```
id      name        age
111     John        30
222     Jill        32
```

Table b

```
id      name        age
111     John        30
222     Jill        33
333     Jacob       35
```

Here we can see that data for 1 row has changed i.e for id 222.

Answer (score 0):

If a row is identified with `(id, name)` then

```
SELECT id, name,
       tableA.age old_age, tableB.age new_age
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB USING (id, name)
WHERE NOT (tableA.age <=> tableB.age)
```

If a row is identified with `(id)` then

```
SELECT id, 
       tableA.name old_name, tableB.name new_name, 
       tableA.age old_age, tableB.age new_age
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB USING (id)
WHERE NOT ((tableA.name, tableA.age) <=> (tableB.name, tableB.age))
```

Comment: not equal (<>) rather than null safe equal (<=>) to rerun for id = 222. and does not cater for name change.

Comment: @P.Salmon 1) We must use `<=>` - w/o it the query will return incorrect output when one or both `age` columns are NULL. But you're correct - I forget NOT operator. 2) I assume that the row is identified with `(id, name)`, if `(id)` identifies the row completely then, of course, the tables must be joined by this column only, and unequiation must be checked for both other columns. Fixed.

Comment: Still doesn't return id 222?

Comment: @P.Salmon Why? fiddle added.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join them using the your key:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.age, b.name, b.age
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b 
    ON a.id = b.id
    AND (a.name <> b.name OR a.age <> b.age)
```

Comment: What if there are 50 columns? I can't have them all in the AND statement